# Give coordinates of line A, find the coordinates of another line meeting line A at an angle.

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, angle, slope

In the diagram, if `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `l`, and `k` are known, how do I calculate `a` and `b`?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: since $~k^\circ~$ is known, $~\displaystyle M = \tan\left(180^\circ - k^\circ\right)$ is known.  Since $M$, which is the **slope** of the line segment given by $\displaystyle \overline{\left(x_2,y_2\right) \left(a,b\right)}~$ is known, then $(a,b)$ must satisfy $~\color{red}{\text{what ?}}$

Comment: The body of your Question should contain a full presentation of the problem you want help with (the setup and the goal).  A diagram can be useful in geometry problems, but in your title you ask about "line $A$" and meeting it at an angle.  Then the body of your Question does not mention line $A$ and it isn't even labelled in the diagram.  You know what you are trying to solve, but splitting things between the title and the diagram in the body of your Question invited confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pivot point is $(x_2 , y_2)$.  Calculate the unit vector pointing from $(x_2, y_2)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$.  This is given by $\mathbf{u}$ where

$ \mathbf{u} = \dfrac{ ( x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2 ) }{\sqrt{ (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 } } $

Now rotate $\mathbf{u}$ by $k^\circ$ clockwise, to get the vector $\mathbf{v}$ which is given by

$ \mathbf{v} = (\cos(k^\circ) \ u_1 + \sin(k^\circ) u_2 , -\sin(k^\circ) u_1 + \cos(k^\circ) u_2 ) $

Finally scale $\mathbf{v}$ by the length $\ell$ and add the resulting vector to $(x_2, y_2)$.  Hence,

$(a,b) = (x_2, y_2) + \ell \mathbf{v} $